# How do I continuously print a file(to terminal) being written to from another script?

Tags: bash

Say I have a script that is reading from a file being printed to. In other words, I have Script A running, which prints its progress in a percentage i.e. 40%. Script A
does this until 100% is reached. The file name being printed to is File_A. Script B looks like the following:

```
source Script_A &

pid=$!

trap "kill $pid 2> /dev/null" EXIT

percent=$(cat File_A | tail -n 1)

while kill -0 $pid 2> /dev/null ; do printf "\r%s" "$percent" ; sleep 1 ; done
```

The result I get from Script B is a line that prints the same percentage; the percentage doesn't change. For example, the terminal looks like so:
40%

It stays at 40%(an arbitrary number I picked for the sake of using an example). EVEN THOUGH Script A is still running AND printing to File_A; the percent in the file is
updating, but Script B won't print these new lines.

I am not sure how to get Script B to print the updated lines in File_A. I'm assuming it has something to do with different shell sessions, but I wouldn't know exactly what question to ask in regards to that; So how can I solve this?

Edit: Here is the code that works.

```
source Script_A &

pid=$!

trap "kill $pid 2> /dev/null" EXIT

while kill -0 $pid 2> /dev/null ; do percent=$(tail -n 1 File_A) ; 
printf "\r%s" "$percent" ; sleep 1 ; done

trap - EXIT
```

The while loop fits on one line; if you have to break the line, use \ like such:

```
while kill -0 $pid 2> /dev/null ; do percent=$(tail -n 1 File_A)\ 
; printf "\r%s" "$percent" ; sleep 1 ; done
```

Comment: stdout id a buffered output, thus anything written in it may *not* be written on disk/file yet. How is File_A created?

Comment: File_A is created by Script A ; Script A has a command that writes to the file using >>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary problem here is that you set `percent` once at the beginning, and never update it. You'd need to put `percent=$(cat File_A | tail -n 1)` *inside* the loop to get it to update each time.

But there's a second problem, which won't prevent it from working, but makes it inefficient (especially if it runs that command over and over and over). The construct `cat somefile | somecommand` is what's sometimes called a ["useless use of `cat`"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat), because `cat` isn't doing anything useful here -- the next program in the pipe can read from the file perfectly well by itself, it doesn't need `cat` to preprocess it. In this case, using `cat` here isn't just useless, it makes `tail` less efficient. Compare these two commands:

```
tail -n 1 File_A        # tail reads directly from File_A
cat File_A | tail -n 1  # tail reads from a pipe from cat
```

In the first version, since `tail` has direct access to the file, it can basically start reading the file *from the end* until it has the last line, print that, and be done. In the version with `cat`, it cannot do this, since `cat` sends the file in order. So in the second version, `tail` (and `cat`) must read through the entire file, just to ignore all but the last line.

So this would be a much better way to do it:

```
n=1

while [ $n -le 100 ] ; do
    percent=$(tail -n 1 File_A)
    printf "\r%s" "$percent"
    sleep 1
    ((n++))
done
```

But there's another method that might work better. Rather than re-checking the file constantly, you could use `tail -f` to "follow" the file and get updates when it changes. However, there's a difficulty here that it doesn't know when to *stop* reading (i.e. when the output has finished), so you have to figure out how to detect that and exit the loop. Something like this might work:

```
tail -n 1 -f File_A | while read percent; do
    printf "\r%s" "$percent"
    [[ "$percent" = "100" ]] && break
done
```

(Note that if the actual final output is something like "100%" instead of just "100", you'd have to change that comparison appropriately.)

Comment: Of course. Makes perfect sense with "useless use of cat". not sure why I missed that. thank you. Also, I edited the code with a trap. I will try your variations tomorrow when I have more time.

Comment: So I placed the variable inside the loop and dropped cat. Works like a charm. Thanks for your help. I tried the last code you suggested, but I keep getting an error in the line with the process ID variable(see the changed code in main post). I'll keep working on it and post another question if needed.

Comment: In the edit, the syntax of the assignment to `pid` is all wrong; I don't know if the problems are in the actual code, or just how you edited it for the question. I'd run the code through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net), fix what it points out, and if it still doesn't work after that put `set -x` at the beginning to get an execution trace as it runs.

Comment: I fixed my example and appended the end with the functional code. In regards to the error I get with your last example, I feel like I should make a separate question as it has to do with what's in the hard brackets. Regardless, again, thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @dvines `$pid=$!` won't work, because you use `$` to *get* the value of a variable, not to *set* it, so use `pid=$!` instead. Also, using `source` to run something in the background is a little weird. The point of `source` is to run another script in the same shell process as the calling script, but backgrounding it with `&` overrides that and makes it run in a subprocess anyway.

Comment: Writing Script_A to a file with '&>' won't show the percent in terminal that's printed from Script_B. Placing Script_A in the background does.